# How to improve texture brush result

Tags: geometry, optimization, blenderkit

I have a couple brushes that I got off of BlenderKit. The link for the brush is this: asset_base_id:66dcf513-f78f-4030-a07a-fcfe9c6a1448 asset_type:brush. I have a cube as a test that has 49152 triangles, and  24576 faces. The end result of the brush looks like this:
[image: End result]

If I smooth out the cube, this is what it looks like:
[image: End result smoothed out]

Do I just need to increase the geometry, or is there a way to optimize the results so that it looks closer to the brush image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, alpha brushes for sculpting require a very dense mesh. Really dense.

Try the default cube with a `Multiresolution modifier` and at least 8 subdivisions = 393,000 faces.
Better 9 (1.6 million) or even 10 subdivisions (6.3 million faces). Then a sculpted line will look like the brush image.